# POST request to an API. Works in postman but getting 404 not found in Angular 6

Tags: angular, api, post, token, postman

I'm trying to connect to an external API using a POST request. This is my code in angular, I have the tokens with me:

```
this.http.post('https://app.skuvault.com/api/products/getProducts',
  {
    "TenantToken": this.my_tenant_token,
    "UserToken": this.my_user_token

  }
)  
  .subscribe((res:Response)=>{
    this.Skuprod=res;
    console.log(this.Skuprod)
  })
}
```

In order to get the product details from this api I need to include the Tokens in the body in json format. When I do this in postman it works and I get the details of the products. However I get a 404 not found error when I try to implement this code in angular. Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: check the network tab see whether the request data is correct or not

Comment: 404 means not found which implies that the URL or ACTION (POST) is incorrect. If your token wasn't being received correctly you would expect a 403 (Forbidden) - assuming the API is implemented correctly.

Comment: I double checked the url. It's correct and I used the exact same url in postman and it worked. But still getting 404 in angular

Comment: I checked the networks tab,in the Request Payload and the tenant token and user token are there. I tried using a proxy config but now im getting a 403 error when using the proxy